# g++ language and CRT reference

Tags: reference, g++

My working environment is Linux, Eclipse CDT and g++ 4.4. Where can I find language and CRT functions reference for this environment? WEB, or maybe it is always installed on my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man "function name"

For example: man fopen, man fwrite.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe I need to install something else? I only installed g++ using sudo apt-get install g++. In addition to man reference, is there some WEB reference, like MSDN Library for MSVC?
Thank you.

Comment: You do need to have your platforms manpages packages installed.